# Can I get Anaconda navigator to see packages on pypi?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install a package which is available on pypi, but I want to do so using Anaconda Navigator. Is this possible? I can see there's a way to add "channels" to Navigator in .condarc, but I have no idea what to add to make it see pypi, or if that's even possible.

I don't want to install the package using pip or even using the conda CLI, I want to use Navigator.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. Hopefully someone else will have some better news!

Comment: To install a package with `conda` or the Navigator, it needs to be available on a conda channel. What's the package and which channels are you using (as configured in your `.condarc` file, if you haven't specified them elsewhere?) Have you checked the `conda-forge` channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding pypi as a channel/repo for Conda is not possible.
Therefore, it is also not possible in Anaconda Navigator.

The only way is [using pip inside an existing conda environment via the Conda CLI](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages).

Sorry.

Comment: The link is bad now.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.